# Algorithm for "adaptive phase rotation" in iZotope RX 8

Tags: adaptive-algorithms

I'm trying to understand how the adaptive phase rotation in iZotope RX 8 works. In the papers I've looked at, the problem is called Peak-to-Average Power Ratio (PAPR) reduction. However, they seem to be for multiplexed signals and cannot be used for audio without greatly altering the sound (e.g. companders).

The problem is really about minimization. Suppose you have 2048 bins, that becomes a 2048-dimensional optimization problem. iZotope RX does this extremely quickly, around 10-100x faster than real time, which is bizarre. Additionally, when the phase is changed too quickly, the frequencies will change as well, which you do not hear after the effect is applied.

This is a really important problem in audio engineering since some microphones intrinsically output asymmetric waveforms.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting topic. I assume that the goal can be expressed as designing a time-variant allpass filter (phase distortion) that minimize amplitude peaks while retaining the frequency magnitude response and keeping time variant behaviour in check so as to not cause glitches or audible changes. Where the motivation is maximizing average signal power without (audible) clipping, exploiting that our hearing is relatively insensitive to frequency-phase response. Almost like transforming the signal into a form that allows easy analysis of skew and curtosis with phase as a driving parameter?

For something like a finite recording of a microphone (with a known acoustic setup and a consistent voice input), I would think that batch processing the entire clip to produce a single global phase distortion might be easier, and might offer clues as to how to solve this in an online manner?

A "dsp-ish" approach might be to do an iir allpass filter with some lookahead and constraints on filter evolution. Or fixed size overlapping window processing. A more adventurous approach might be to segment the input into "energetic" and "non-energetic" segments, and process each energetic segment with a constant distortion, putting the "time variant behaviour" into segments of non-signal.

Predicting time-domain amplitude peaks from a dft/fft representation where you are free to fiddle with the phase seems a bit fiddly. Someone might have a nice mathematical formulation of that except brute forcing it. I do believe that something similar is a concern for OFDM communication modulation - they want to maximize signal power from a set of DFT basis functions, but not drive the radio amplifier into nonlinear territory(?). For single-speaker signals, perhaps resynthesizing the signal as a set of sinoids (possibly a harmonic series + residual "noise") could offer some possibilities.